# How to determine image of function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I have a continuous function
$$f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R,$$
for $a,b \in \mathbb R,a < b$. $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$.

How can I determine The image of $f(|a,b|)$?

Comment: I think you mean $f([a,b])$.  The intermediate value theorem comes to mind.  Can you prove that $f([a,b])$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$? Is it a closed interval?

Comment: @Michael continuity alone implies that $f([a,b])$ is an interval. I don't see why we need that it has a derivative in the open interval.

Comment: @yanko Yes, that seems like unimportant information. Perhaps taking derivatives will help find the extrema though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then the Intermediate Value Theorem and Extreme Value Theorem say that  $f$ attains an absolute maximum and absolute minimum value on $[a,b]$. In fact the image of $f$ will be the *closed* interval from this min. value to the max. value.

If $f$ is also differentiable on $(a,b)$, then we have the so-called Closed Interval Method that says

1. Find all critical numbers of $f$ (that is all numbers $c$ where $f'(c) = 0$ or where $f'(c)$ doesn't exist)
2. Let $m$ be the smallest number of $f(a), f(b)$, and $f(c)$ where $c$ is a critical number. Let $M$ be the largest from this list of numbers.

Then the image of $f$ is $[m,M]$.